# CMake Fails To Compile "relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol"

Tags: cmake

I am trying to make a portable framework library that works between Linux and Windows, however whenever I compile my code on Linux I keep running into an error:

```
"/usr/bin/ld: ../extern/SDL2_ttf/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `TTF_CloseFont' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC"
```

This error doesn't occur on Windows only on Linux. I am totally lost on how to fix it as nothing has worked except for removing SHARED from add_library which removed DLLs and makes my code unusable. If you have any ideas on how to fix this please comment below. Thanks in advance!

**Main CMakeList.txt**

```
add_subdirectory(extern)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

set(PROJECT_NAME Project)

project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 0.1.0)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

**Source CMakeList.txt**

```
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

file(GLOB EXTERN_SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/stb/include/*.h" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/stb/src/*.cpp" )

include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Chassis2D" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/include/" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2_ttf" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/stb/include/")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${EXTERN_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC SDL2 SDL2_ttf box2d soloud)

set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin"
)
```

**External Libraries CMakeList.txt**

```
set(SDL_STATIC OFF)
add_subdirectory(SDL2)
add_library(SDL2::SDL2 ALIAS SDL2)

add_subdirectory(freetype)
add_library(Freetype::Freetype ALIAS freetype)

add_subdirectory(SDL2_ttf)

set(SOLOUD_BACKEND_COREAUDIO OFF)
set(SOLOUD_BACKEND_OPENSLES OFF)
set(SOLOUD_BACKEND_XAUDIO2 OFF)
set(SOLOUD_BACKEND_WINM OFF)
set(SOLOUD_BACKEND_WASAPI OFF)
set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/include")
add_subdirectory(SoLoud/contrib)

add_subdirectory(Box2D)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` only influences targets defined after it has been set. However, you're setting `CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` to `ON` after including the `extern` subdirectory, which is why the external libraries are not built with position-independent code.